# Tooltip in the network graph is flashing on and off

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, force-layout

I am creating a tooltip for the network graph in d3js where each node have circle and text.

What I am trying to do is that when user try to mouseover/mouseout on the circle/text the tooltip is getting show/hide accordingly. So when the user mouseover from circle to text the tooltip is flashing on and off and changing the position of the tooltip. This is because that I have given the show/hide event to both the element like this.

```
circles.on("mouseover", showDetails);
circles.on("mouseout", hideDetails);
text.on("mouseover", showDetails);
text.on("mouseout", hideDetails);
```

and also  when I hover the some nodes the tooltip div will be at the top of the cursor so when I move up the cursor the the mouse pointer will be hover the div and the tooltip is flashed on and off.

[image: network graph]

Is it possible to combine the text, circle and tooltip div for a particular node as a single element and also to show the tooltip without the frequent changing in the position. Is there any other possibilities to do this?

He is my jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/AkAdeMoK/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `circles.on("mousemove", showDetails);`

I alse added css

```
svg text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is how it looks like now - http://jsbin.com/omaguJO/1